# Disconnect a connect call using Twilio Android client

Tags: android, twilio

I am using Twilio android client. `device.connect()` is working fine but can't able to disconnect the connected call, though the user (I dialed to) if hangup then the call will be disconnected. I have tried with `device.disconnectAll()` and `connection.disconnect()`, both are not working. Please guide me wher i'm wrong.

Simple:
Caller can't be able to disconnect the call while callee can.

Thank in Advance.

To connect the call

```
HashMap<String, String> p = new HashMap<String, String>();
p.put("PhoneNumber", personToCall);
p.put(Connection.IncomingParameterFromKey, (String) device.getCapabilities().get(Device.Capability.CLIENT_NAME));
p.put(Connection.IncomingParameterToKey, personToCall);
device.connect(p, this);
```

and to disconnect

```
connection.disconnect()
```

Comment: First step, post the code. Without seeing the code, all we can really do is guess what you might be doing wrong, and that's a waste of your time just as much as it is ours. :D)  You can use this [edit] link to add more details. Good luck!

Comment: Also, if you're seeing any error messages, please post those as well.

Comment: @jmort253 no error message i can see.

Comment: Where are you getting the `connection` object from? According to the docs, device.connect returns a connection object.

Comment: from `onConnecting(Connection connection)` callback. Well i have tried from `device.connect()` too but no success.

Comment: I don't see that in your code...

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear in your code how you're obtaining the connection object, which is one of two pivotal pieces of the Twilio client.

The Twilio Client documentation has an example on [making outbound calls](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client/make-outgoing-call):

```
import com.twilio.client.Connection;
import com.twilio.client.Device;
import com.twilio.client.Twilio;


public class MonkeyPhone implements Twilio.InitListener
{
    private Device device;
    private Connection connection;

    /* ... other methods ... */

    public void connect()
    {
        connection = device.connect(null /* parameters */, null /* ConnectionListener */);
        if (connection == null)
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create new connection");
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize()
    {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
        if (device != null)
            device.release();
    }
}
```

In the example, when you call device.connect(), a connection object is returned and stored as a property in the object so it can be referenced again later on.  In the finalize method, we call connection.disconnect() to terminate the call.

If you're not calling disconnect on the connection object returned from device.connect() the call may not disconnect properly.  See the Twilio documentation for [Device.connect](http://www.twilio.com/docs/client/android/Device#connect_java_util_Map__ConnectionListener_) for more details.

Comment: Now i have grabbed the connection object from `device.connect()` but no sucess :( ..

Comment: Did you actually start by downloading their demo and getting it to run? That's usually the first thing to do when you're working with something new is to get *their* project running first, that way you have something that actually works to start with before you start doing your own thing...

Comment: In demo they are just initialzing Twilio.

Comment: You sure about that? It sure looks to me like they're walking you through setting up an Android demo, complete with an input box for a phone number, a call button, and a hangup button:  http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client/make-outgoing-call

Comment: I can't imagine them having you create buttons that do nothing. You should really give that a try.  I suspect you're missing something that would become more clear by just running their examples first. Good luck! :)

Comment: Yes i am pretty sure about this.

Comment: Check out this section on hanging up the call. http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client/hang-up-call

Comment: @jmort253 have you Implemented code for incoming call in android service? I have implemented code in activity which is working fine but when I integrate that code into Service I get null values of Device and Connection.